# How to get all children tags from XML(fast info document) in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simple-html-dom

I have problem in code when i parse the XML to Array.it returns some tags and  not the complete tags.I want to get all tags inside in soap response.I have xml file.and upload this file.

**Here is data.txt file below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="<a rel="nofollow" class="external free" href="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/</a>"
  xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Body>
     <retrieveResponse>
        <result xsi:type="sf:sObject">
           <id>123</id>
           <description>description</description>
           <name>testing</imran>
           <cnic>23198398213</cnic>
        </result>
     </retrieveResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
    ini_set("memory_limit", "44879M");
    include("dom.php");
    $xml = str_get_html( file_get_contents("data.txt") );
    $final = array();
    $result = $xml->find("result");
    foreach($result as $r){

        $tag = $r->children();
        $one = array();
        foreach($tag as $child){
            $tag = $child->tag;
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($tag); echo "<br>";

            if( stristr($tag, ":") ){
                list($com, $tag) = explode(":", $tag);

            }
            $one[$tag]  =  trim(strip_tags($child->innertext));
        }
        $final[] = $one;
        //print_r($final); exit;
    }
    print_r($final);
?>
```

**My output:**

```
id
description
name
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [description] => description
            [name] => testing             23198398213
        )
)
```

**My expected output should:**

```
id
description
name
cnic
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [description] => description
            [name] => testing   
            [cnic] =>   23198398213       
        )
)
```

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Fix your xml `<name>testing</imran>`

Comment: There are a few more problems with your XML - you don't define the xsi namespace and your xmlns:soapenv namespace isn't right.

Comment: @NigelRen this xml info set i want to convert any soap v1.2 message in Array/JSON. this script is correct or not for different soap messages?

Comment: @NigelRen please confirm if any change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by simple_html_dom trying to correct your XML.  There are a few issues with it and if they were resolved, you could load it much more efficiently with either DOMDocument or SimpleXML.

If you corrected the element

```
<name>testing</imran>
```

as the html parser is trying to correct the structure, it's taking this and the `<cnic>` element as one piece of data.  Change this to

```
<name>testing</name>
```

and your output changes to...

```
<pre>id<br><pre>description<br><pre>name<br><pre>cnic<br>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [description] => description
            [name] => testing
            [cnic] => 23198398213
        )

)
```

If you corrected your XML, then you could do the following (XML included)...

```
$data = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Body>
     <retrieveResponse>
        <result xsi:type="sf:sObject">
           <id>123</id>
           <description>description</description>
           <name>testing</name>
           <cnic>23198398213</cnic>
        </result>
     </retrieveResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("def", "urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com");
$result = $xml->xpath("//def:result");
$final = array();
foreach ( $result[0]->children() as $element ) {
    $final [ $element->getName() ] = (string)$element;
}
print_r($final);
```