# How to get Multilevel tag from SOAP Message and make array using simpledomhtml in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simple-html-dom

I have problem in code, when i parse XML to Array get single array of `XML`.Actually I want to parse all soap v1.2 response message in array/json.and fetch multiple array if exits, For example multiple data in array exist in array and wrapped single array according to give expected output.

Here is my code:

**data.txt file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="<a rel="nofollow" class="external free" href="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/</a>"
  xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Body>
        <getResponse>
            <result xsi:type="sf:sObject">
             <id>123</id>
             <description>description</description>
             <name>testing</name>
             <cnic>23198398213</cnic>
          </result>
         <result xsi:type="sf:sObject">
             <id>567</id>
             <description>LOrem ipsum des</description>
             <name>name testing</name>
             <cnic>2827489024243</cnic>
          </result>
        </getResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
    ini_set("memory_limit", "44879M");
    include("dom.php");
    $xml = str_get_html( file_get_contents("data.txt") );
    $final = array();
    $result = $xml->find("result");
    foreach($result as $r){
        $tag = $r->children();
        $one = array();
        foreach($tag as $child){
            $tag = $child->tag;
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($tag); echo "<br>";

            if( stristr($tag, ":") ){
                list($com, $tag) = explode(":", $tag);
            }
            $one[$tag]  =  trim(strip_tags($child->innertext));
        }
        $final[] = $one;
    }
    print_r($final);
?>
```

**My expected output should:**

```
Array
(
   [getResponse] => Array(
       [result]=> Array(
          [0] =>  Array(
               [id] => 123
               [description] => description
               [name] => testing   
               [cnic] =>   23198398213       
             )
          [1] =>  Array(
               [id] => 567
               [description] => LOrem ipsum des
               [name] => name testing
               [cnic] =>   2827489024243
             )
           )

        )
)
```

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: SOAP messages are XML, not HTML. Start by using an XML processing tool, like DOM.

Comment: @DaveRandom right but please help of my above script

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but you should probably be using the PHP `SoapClient` class.

Comment: @jjok i want get array from above xml that i defined in question description

Comment: You have put your **expected output**. Where is your **current output**. We may be able to help you more then...

Comment: If you insist on using SimpleHtmlDom then you probably won't be able to achieve what you want. It's simply not capable of dealing with XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all children tags from XML(fast info document) using simplehtmldom in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821727/how-to-get-all-children-tags-from-xmlfast-info-document-using-simplehtmldom-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would best of using a recursive solution to pass a hierarchy into an array.  This code starts off with each element and if there are any sub-nodes, then it calls the same routine again to build the data for that sub set of data.

```
require_once "dom.php";

function xmlToArray ( simple_html_dom_node $base )  {
    $newData = [];
    foreach ( $base->children as $newElement )  {
        if ( $newElement->has_child() === true ) {
            $addData = xmlToArray($newElement);
            // if element already exists
            if ( isset($newData [ $newElement->tag ]) ) {
                // if not already a list of elements
                if ( !isset($newData [ $newElement->tag ][0])) {
                    // Turn into an array of elements
                    $newData [ $newElement->tag ] = [$newData [ $newElement->tag ]];
                }
                // Add data to end
                $newData [ $newElement->tag ][] = $addData;
            }
            else    {
                $newData [ $newElement->tag ] = $addData;
            }
        }
        else    {
            $newData [ $newElement->tag ] = $newElement->innertext;
        }
    }
    return $newData;
}
$xml = str_get_html( file_get_contents("data.txt") ); 
$final = xmlToArray ( $xml->root->find("soapenv:Body")[0] );
print_r($final);
```

The recursive routine is started with the content of the `<soapenv:Body>` tag and then processes this content.

This outputs...

```
Array
(
    [getresponse] => Array
        (
            [result] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [description] => description
                    [name] => testing
                    [cnic] => 23198398213
                )

        )

)
```

I would still recommend to look into using SimpleXML or DOMDocument, but this should work with what you already have.

Comment: I want to handle multilevel xml please see
http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c1e8e320af82ae02002cf9733126218b
Add multilevel array in result

Comment: see problem of multilevel ?

Comment: can you change the format according to above output that i mentioned in question

Comment: I will have a look in the morning.

Comment: Thanks i am waiting of your response

Comment: I've updated the code, it makes it more complex, but this is expected when asking more of such a small function.

Comment: Great, very Thanks and pleasure, i try to understand according to your logic.

Comment: i have run the code but it's return same first result two times can you check this please?

Comment: are you checking this please?

Comment: Sorry - updated line `$newData [ $newElement->tag ] = [$newData [ $newElement->tag ]];`